# How to dynamically change the document reference in a formula Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change a tab reference dynamically in a formula in Excel. I can't seem to figure this out.
This is my situation:
Document reference in Excel: `='P:TestLocation\[TestFile.xlsx]01'!A1`

The tab 01 has to change in 02 based on cel B1 in the current file. Cell B1 contains: `2021-01`.

A formula like this doesn't work: `='P:TestLocation\[TestFile.xlsx]&RIGHT(B1;2)&'!A1` or `=CONCAT('P:TestLocation\[TestFile.xlsx];RIGHT(B1;2);'!A1)`

Edit: I would like to work with closed workbooks.

Any thoughts on this matter? Any help is appreciated!

Kind regards,

Shaney

Comment: You will be needing `INDIRECT` formula to achieve this and it will work with open workbooks.

Comment: I prefer to work with closed workbooks. Is there another solution?